# How Can I pass Start and end date parameter in Powerbi URL

Tags: azure, powerbi

How can I pass the start and end date parameter in the URL so that the report gets sorted out as I need to be. How to show the data in between those date parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters ?

Comment: Yes something like that But how can I pass the start and end date values there??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by start and end dates. With the link I provided, you're able to do filtering based on values in the URL. Add a few additional tables (one for start dates and the other for end dates), add column for the date value and a column for date value as string in both tables, add references to those tables and values in the URL and that should be it.

Comment: I want to pass the parameter that shows the data in between those dates is that possible in Powerbi??